# ANT property environment="env" unable to retrieve it in JAVA but works fine if run as ant command

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables

I've a build file which will be called from java. Please find the build.xml below.

```
<property environment="env"/>
  <echo message="${env.PATH}"/>
  <echo message="${env.SSH_CONNECTION}"/>
  <echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
  <echo message="${env.HOME}"/>
  <echo message="${env.IS_HOME}"/>
  <echo message="${basedir}"/>
```

Unable to fetch the environment variables if its run through java class. But the same works fine if run as ant command like "ant". Please help

iF run as JAVA then error is

```
--- MESSAGE LOGGED
Property ${env.JAVA_HOME} has not been set
--- MESSAGE LOGGED
     [echo] ${env.JAVA_HOME}
```

But i could see that the environment variables are set fine. If i echo the variables command line , im able to see the value.

Comment: How are you running it from Java?

Comment: Its through an external tool. We are using intershop studio where we have a job console which can be used to trigger the job. So the job inturn is nothing but a java file which inturn calls the build script

Comment: do you  set  env  vars  with  "set"  or  "export"?   I was able  to get  them if  vars are  set with  export  in same session but had  same issues with  the  ones  defined  with set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the intershop studio sets environment variables for spawned processes (jobs). I cannot check it as it's a commercial product.

But for instance in Jenkins you have [a list of environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) which are passed to your job.

Check the documentation for the intershop studio.

Comment: Thanks Pavliv. I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Any environment variables set or pulled into Ant are instance variables.... they are only available to that instance of Ant and any process that Ant creates / calls.

I would need to see more of how you are running the java command in order to know if your JAVA_HOME is getting over ridden elsewhere.

## EDIT:

I think I found the issue.... In a java program (aka, a class you are running) you need to explicitly call getenv in order to import the environment variables for that instance of the java program. THEN, you need to pass that environment (aand all the variables in it) to the call to Ant so ant has access to it.

By default, ant gathers up all the enviroment variables.  Java needs an explicit call to get the environment variables.

Found via: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: In intershop we have intershop studio (similar to eclipse) where we have a UI called SMC (scheduler) where we run the jobs. So once we select the job and click run it calls the java program which in turn calls the build script. This is happening in remote server which is a linux environment. I had a check on $JAVA_HOME and it points to "eserver/engine/jdk" which is the default jdk that comes as part of intershop

Comment: Moreover its not an issue with JAVA_HOME alone. None of the environment variables are accessible if run through java. But im able to echo the value once logged in to linux and execute it on command line

Comment: You might need to see the necessary property values into a .properties file, and then read that in to the java command line so that they are available internally.

Comment: But im not trying to get it in java, im using those in my ant build script only. But the invocation of ant script happens through java

Comment: I think I found the issue....  In a java program (aka, a class you are running) you need to explicitly call getenv in order to import that instance of the java programs current environment.

THEN, you probably need to pass that environment (all all the variables in it) to the call to Ant.

Found via:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: Thanks Robin.Let me check and get back

Comment: Issue Resolved. Its was due to memory allocation issue. Had check on appserver log and **i could see that it throws java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/env": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory**. After allocating the right memort in Unix it started running.

Comment: Glad to hear you got a resolution!